# Fire event from one object to notify end of frame

Tags: actionscript-3, events, instance, frame, movieclip

I am relatively new to AS and want to know how I can notify that an object I imported has reached it's final frame. Basically I want to create a .fla with a class file maybe and import the .swf as a movieclip in an other fla and maybe have multiple instances of that imported movieclip. Now I would like to know how I can get notified that one instance of the imported movieclip has reached the final frame.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire event with `dispatchEvent(new Event("eventname"))`.
Write `dispatchEvent` on end of frame.

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

and, listen for the event:

```
mc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, endOfFrameHandler);
function endOfFrameHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MovieClip' undocumented `addFrameScript()` method , like:

```
mc.addFrameScript( mc.totalFrames - 1 , lastFrameHandler);

function lastFrameHandler():void{
    //
    // mc.stop();
    //
}
```

With `addFrameScript`  you don't need to put any code in `.fla`' frames/timeline!

Comment: Knew about this method from other thread. I added stop to the last frame and in that last frame added a property that turned to true when last frame is hit. After importing this movieclip I still had to listen for that property to trun to true. When I did th listening with a while I was propted with an error that the movieclip has exceeded some seconds runtime..etc