# Actionscript 3 - Wait till MovieClip animation has finished before executing next line

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timeout

Say I have this AS3 code:

```
playButtonContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playButtonClicked);

function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent) {
    instructionsContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
    analysisScreenContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
    playButtonContainer.gotoAndPlay(2); 
    statusDescriptionContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Inside `instructionsContainer`, `analysisScreenCnotainer`, `playButtonContainer` and `statusDescriptionContainer` is a MovieClip which has its own timeline and animation.

As you can see, I have 4 different MovieClips playing one after another. How do I make it so that

```
statusDescriptionContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

executes only after the animation for

```
playButtonContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

finishes executing and

```
playButtonContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

executes only after the

```
playButtonContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

animation is finished?

Comment: Here you have two different approaches examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722342/fire-event-from-one-object-to-notify-end-of-frame

Answer (score 1):

What Cherniv suggested you or you could add an event listener and just listen to enter frame. There you just check whether the currentFrame equals the totalFrames. Or you could extend movieclip:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class AdvancedMovieClip extends MovieClip {

        public function AdvancedMovieClip() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
            if(this.currentFrame == this.totalFrames) {
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            }
        }

        public function destroy():void {
            this.stop();
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
playButtonContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playButtonClickedHandler, false, 0, true);

function playButtonClickedHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace('instructionsContainer');
    instructionsContainer.addFrameScript(instructionsContainer.totalFrames -1, playStatusDescriptor);
    instructionsContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function playStatusDescriptor():void
{
    instructionsContainer.stop();
    trace('statusDescriptionContainer');
    statusDescriptionContainer.addFrameScript(statusDescriptionContainer.totalFrames -1, playAnalysisScreen);
    statusDescriptionContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function playAnalysisScreen():void
{
    statusDescriptionContainer.stop();
    trace('playAnalysisScreen');
    analysisScreenContainer.addFrameScript(analysisScreenContainer.totalFrames -1, playAnotherButton);
    analysisScreenContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function playAnotherButton():void
{
    analysisScreenContainer.stop();
    trace('playAnotherButton');
    anotherScreenContainer.addFrameScript(anotherScreenContainer.totalFrames -1, somethingElse);
    anotherScreenContainer.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function somethingElse():void
{
    anotherScreenContainer.stop();
    trace('somethingElse');
}
```